# Trying to change background image of UISwitch

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uiswitch

Code:

```
 let switchTerms = UISwitch(frame:CGRectMake(XPos, YPos, Width, Height))
        switchTerms.addTarget(self, action: "switchTermsAction:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
         switchTerms.onImage = UIImage(named:"SIGN-UP-toggle-Active.png")
        scrollSignUp!.addSubview(switchTerms);

 func switchTermsAction(sender:UISwitch){

        if sender.on{

            sender.onImage = UIImage(named:"SIGN-UP-toggle-Active.png")
        }
        else{
            sender.offImage = UIImage(named:"SIGN-UP-toggle-DeActive.png")
        }
    }
```

I tried to change background image of UISwitch when it is changed.
Seems background image is not set.

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4):

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *genderSwitchBackgroundImageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *genderSwitch;

...

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.genderSwitch.onTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.genderSwitch.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [self genderSwitchValueChanged];
}

- (IBAction)genderSwitchValueChanged {
    self.genderSwitchBackgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:(self.genderSwitch.isOn ? @"toggle_male" : @"toggle_female")];
}
```

[image: example]

[image: example]

Swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var genderSwitchBackgroundImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var genderSwitch: UISwitch!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        genderSwitch.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        genderSwitch.onTintColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        genderSwitchValueChanged()
    }

    @IBAction func genderSwitchValueChanged() {
        genderSwitchBackgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named:genderSwitch.on ? "toggle_male" : "toggle_female")
    }
}
```

Comment: Max, are you saying you put the image BELOW the switch? So the image is the same size as the normal switch?

Comment: @Mark Moeykens yep

Comment: Yeah, that seems to work. Made the backgrounds with a height of 31 and a width of 51 put both behind the switch. Seems to work fine. Wish there was a more elegant way.

Comment: it really works ) I used this approach in real project. and I think it's better than "UIButton-approach"

Answer (score 2):

`onImage` and `offImage` properties have no effect since iOS7 according to Apple docs

Try to create a UIButton, and set an image on this button according to the `selected:Bool` property to make it behave like a Switch

When you press the button, make `sender.selected = !sender.selected` and then refresh the image. You will have a custom switch !

Comment: such switch does not have animation